# Does Xamarin Essentials have its own biometrics implementation?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.essentials

I'm Trying to use xamarin essentials at Its fullest , but I dont want to use the fingerprint plugin that I have , does xamarin essentials have a implementation for fingerprint authnetication without the use of a plugin?

Comment: I've read the documentation, but I didn't find anything that leads me to fingerprint authentication , I'm just trying to confirm or to find a solution to my problem

Comment: Essentials does not contain a biometric feature.  That's why its not listed in the docs.

Comment: There is an [issue](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/issues/71) open for it. It looks like they're waiting for more support for AndroidX library before implementing.

Comment: You could implement it by using DependencyService .Check  https://jj09.net/adding-biometrics-authentication-to-xamarin-ios-touch-id-face-id-and-xamarin-android-fingerprint/ . And here is a similar issue which maybe can help you .https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/156798/how-to-use-touch-id-fingerprint-to-authenticate-in-xamarin-ios-native-app